# Render depth map to image with python script

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I'm trying to render an object from different views using blender. While I worked out how this can be achieved by the means of a python script, I'm stuck on my next task: I also want to dump the depthmap for every rendered image. What I've found so far is [this link](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Render/Post_Process/Passes), so I assume that I need to somehow disable render passes to get my desired result? How would I do that through the python interface? Or is there an easier way?

Edit: I found another reference how to do this in the GUI: http://www.cs.tut.fi/kurssit/SGN-5406/vrlab2012/blender-manual.pdf. How could I automate this with a python script?

Comment: Cycles or Blender Internal? If possible please provide a test scene. Also might be a good idea to split up your question...

Comment: Blender internal would be enough for my purposes. The scene is very simple, only a single mesh (loaded from an .obj file) placed in origin. Just an example of how to do it with the default cube woud be enough for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From various sources I found out how to assemble a render graph to put out the depth map (scaled to the range [0, 255]):

```
# Set up rendering of depth map:
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links

# clear default nodes
for n in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(n)

# create input render layer node
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')

map = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeMapValue")
# Size is chosen kind of arbitrarily, try out until you're satisfied with resulting depth map.
map.size = [0.08]
map.use_min = True
map.min = [0]
map.use_max = True
map.max = [255]
links.new(rl.outputs[2], map.inputs[0])

invert = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeInvert")
links.new(map.outputs[0], invert.inputs[1])

# The viewer can come in handy for inspecting the results in the GUI
depthViewer = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeViewer")
links.new(invert.outputs[0], depthViewer.inputs[0])
# Use alpha from input.
links.new(rl.outputs[1], depthViewer.inputs[1])
```

The output can then be saved to a file using a *File Output* node:

```
# create a file output node and set the path
fileOutput = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
fileOutput.base_path = "/my_path/"
links.new(invert.outputs[0], fileOutput.inputs[0])
```

Whenever a render is triggered, the depth map will be dumped into the `base_path` specified.

Comment: Great! Just an idea: you could also create an output node to save the file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! A file output node would indeed be better for my purposes.

Comment: Just wondering if the z value represents the distance between a surface point and the sensor?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with `CompositorNodeMapValue`, setting the size/min/max to values that got a good reading. Using the `CompositorNodeMapRange` was more helpful.

You can set the values intuitively, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPwdLOSpMUA&t=435s) is good intro.

For setting these same parameters from that video in the api, you would set

`map.inputs[1].default_value` = (min value you will be getting)

`map.inputs[2].default_value` = (max value you will be getting)

`map.inputs[3].default_value` = (min value you will map to)

`map.inputs[4].default_value` = (max value you will map to)

The last two values are typically 0 and 1, but if you want your depth map to be lighter if the object is closer to the camera, they will be 1 and 0 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the suggested tips have been useful, but for blender 3.4.1 with Eevee renderer I had to do extra steps, which I add for reference (the main thing is enabling the Z pass):

```
# Useful scene variables
scn = bpy.context.scene
cam = scn.camera
output_path = scn.render.filepath
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links

bpy.context.scene.render.use_compositing = True
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
bpy.context.scene.view_layers[0].use_pass_z = True

for n in tree.nodes:
  tree.nodes.remove(n)
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')

vl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')
vl.use_alpha = True
links.new(rl.outputs[0], vl.inputs[0])  # link Image to Viewer Image RGB
links.new(rl.outputs['Depth'], vl.inputs[1])  # link Render Z to Viewer Image Alpha
```

Then render and store as a numpy array:

```
bpy.ops.render.render()

pixels = np.array(bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels)
resolution = int(np.sqrt(len(pixels)/4))
#reshaping into image array 4 channel (rgbz)
image_with_depth = pixels.reshape(resolution,resolution,4)
```